# How to disable direct connect IP address

Tags: apache, cloudflare

I have 3 sites hosting on a server with same ip. I am using cloudflare but some sites are able to find the server IP using "direct connect IP" Is there a way to disable it ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a P2P or gaming app on your server is broadcasting your IP. See if it can be configured to broadcast your FQDN instead.